# Additive bijection concept.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Could someone help me understand what is meant  by additive bijection ?

Especially between the sets $(Z^*_7,\cdot)$ and $(Z_6,+)$
where $Z^*_7 = Z_7/{[0]}$.

Also is $(Z^*_7,\cdot)$ the set of module 7 where only scalar multiplication is defined?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

$(Z^{*}_7,.)$ is a multiplicative group and $(Z_6,+)$ is an additive group. But both are cyclic group of order $6$.

$Z_7^*=\langle [3]_7 \rangle$ and $Z_6=\langle [1]_6 \rangle$.

One of the isomorphism $f:(Z^{*}_7,.)\to(Z_6,+)$ is defined by $f([3]_7^n)=[n]_6$.

I think, isomorphism is meant by "additive bijection".

Comment: Thank you, also what do you mean by multiplicative group? And what is the reasoning that brought you to use $3^n$ out of nowhere?That's what I can't understand

Comment: Multiplicative group means notations related with the operation in the group looks like "natural" multiplication (Which we usually do in daily life).